# Текстовой редактор для удаленного хоста

Tags: ide

У меня есть виртуальная машина, на ней ведется разработка.
Я конекчусь к ней через пути и делаю дела, но я устал от `vim'a`.
Можно ли как нибудь скормить текстовому редактору файлы с удаленного хоста?

Comment: komodo может работать удалённо, по ftp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов:

1. Использоваться IDE у себя локально, большинство IDE умеют работать через `FTP` и `SSH` туннели.
2. Можно использоваться СКВ (`svn, git, mercurial`). Такие как `github` или `bitbucket`. Последний выигрывает в сторону приватного репозитория.
   Много плюсов использования системы контроля версий, к тому же достаточно удобно.
   Можно использовать ту виртуальную машину в качестве репозитория (+1 к безопасности утечки кода в `public`)
3. Использовать сетевые файловые системы, windows share и ему подобные.
   В дополнение люди пользуются сервисами аля dropbox.
4. `Vim` реально удобная штука, для PHP самое оно :)

Comment: dropbox точно не для этого.

Answer (score 2):

можно, но vim лучше:) Реально лучше. Конкуренцию может только emacs составить. Но на медленных подключениях только vim.

Но если так сильно хочется мучиться с gui, то можно удаленный каталог подключить себе. Под [windows](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/jp107/xp-remote/ssh-map/) так, либо [так](http://code.google.com/p/win-sshfs/), а под линуксом [ssh fs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html), который уже есть практически в любом нормальном дистрибутиве и вперед.

Но будьте готовы к разным фокусам.

Comment: А поднять репозиторий, а отлаживать локально не вариант?

Comment: репозиторий? может имелось ввиду что-то в виде svn/git/mercurial и с помощью него заливать на удаленный сервер push'ем. А разработку вести локально.

Comment: vim круче ничего нет, просто нужно держать сразу много файлов открытых, вим в этом слабоват.

Comment: в виме есть вкладки и буфера. работает отлично.